# @RequestParam is not receiving value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, bad-request

In my Application I want to check after the user input in my phone number input field that if that phone number is present on DB or not for that I use an `onchange` event to send the number instantly on Input field the issue is When I am sending data from this input field to check the data is not received by @RequestParam and my value is getting null please help me here what I am doing wrong and what should be done.
Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/indoUser")
public class UserController {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/validate-phn",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public APIResponseModal checkPhonePresent(@ModelAttribute String phoneNumber) {
        logger.info("Check Phone MEthod");
        logger.info(phoneNumber);
        List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();
        APIResponseModal apiResponse = new Utils().getDefaultApiResponse();
        try {
            if(Utils.isNotNull(phoneNumber)) {
                Boolean isExists =  userService.phoneNumberExists(phoneNumber, errorList);
                if(isExists) {
                    apiResponse.setMessage("Number already Present please login with OTP !");
                    apiResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                }else {
                    apiResponse.setMessage("Number is New ");
                    apiResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return apiResponse;
    }
}
```

**Input fields**

```
function fetchAndDisplayCountryList(){
    
    var ajaxObject = new MasterAjax();
    ajaxObject.requestType = "POST";
    ajaxObject.url = "getCountryList";
    ajaxObject.contentType = false;
    ajaxObject.data = null;
    ajaxObject.requestData(function(responseData) {
        if (responseData.status == "OK") {
            countryList = JSON.parse(responseData.data);
            let content = "<select style=\"padding: 0;\"  id=\"leadCountry\" onchange=\"displayISDCode();\" class=\"inputTxt\" required=\"required\" >" +
                            "<option value=\"-1\"> Country </option>";
            for(let k=0;k<countryList.length;k++){
                content += "<option value="+countryList[k].id+">"+countryList[k].countryName+"</option>";
            }
            content += "</select>";
            $(".country").html(content);
            
        } else {
            //NO COUNTRY LIST RECEIVED
        }
    });
}

function displayISDCode(){
    let countryId = document.getElementById("leadCountry").value;
    let isdCode = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < countryList.length; i++) {
        if(countryList[i].id == countryId){
            isdCode =   countryList[i].countryPhoneCode;
        }
    }
    phoneContent= "<input type=\"tel\" class=\"inputTxt\" id=\"phoneNumber\" value="+isdCode+"  maxlength=\"15\" onchange=\"checkPhoneNumber();\" name=\"phoneNumber\" required=\"required\" placeholder=\"\">"+
        "<label for=\"\"class=\"inputlab\">Phone Number</label>";
    
        $(".phonediv").html(phoneContent);
}
```

**AJAX REquest**

```
function checkPhoneNumber(){
    console.log("Check phone is called")
//  let formData = new FormData();
//  formData.append("phoneNumber", $("#storeOpenTime").val());
    let phone = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
    console.log("Value of phone is :" + phone);
    var obj = new MasterAjax();
    obj.requestType = "POST";
    obj.url = "indoUser/validate-phn";
    obj.data = phone;
    console.log("Before sending the data Date is :  :   "+obj.data)
    obj.contentType = false;
    obj.processData = false;
    obj.dataType= "application/json";
    obj.requestData(function(responseData){
        console.log(responseData);
        if(responseData.status == "OK" || responseData.status == "ok"){
//          toastSuccessAlert(responseData.message);
            console.log(responseData)
        }else{
//          toastDangerAlert("Failed",responseData.message)
            console.log(responseData)
        }
    }); 
    
    
}
```

**BROWSER CONSOLE**

```
data: null
​
message: "Unable to process the request!"
​
status: "BAD_REQUEST"
```

**IDE console**

```
 Check Phone MEthod
2021-05-23 12:24:06.142  INFO 14972 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.I.e.U.Controller.UserController        : null
```

Comment: What if you use RequestBody instead of ModelAttribute? Or in addition to!

Comment: @fast-reflexes thanks, I also just fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RequestBody worked for me instead of @ModelAttribute